# Effect of Code Execution Order

Tags: java, methods

The problem I'm having is that code stops working when I change the order.

For example in the following code my objects don't show up unless they are first. My robot does not show up unless its on top. If I move `makeWalls` to the bottom the walls disappear.

My question is, is there any way I can structure my code so that the order does not matter and everything works together?

```
import becker.robots.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class Assignment4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        City newYork = new City();

        makeWalls(newYork);
        Robot hammer = new Robot(newYork, 1, 1, Direction.EAST);
        Thing picnic= new Thing(newYork, 2,3);
        Thing apple= new Thing(newYork, 2,4);
        Thing corndog= new Thing(newYork, 2,4);
        Thing cottoncandy= new Thing(newYork, 2,4);
        Thing routine= new Thing(newYork, 1,4);
        Thing man= new Thing(newYork, 3,4);
        Thing eating= new Thing(newYork, 5,4);
        Thing cookies= new Thing(newYork, 4,4);
        makeRobotReach(hammer);
    }

    // Robot method
    public static void makeRobotReach(Robot r){
        while(r.frontIsClear()){
            r.move();
        }
    }

    public static void makeWalls(City city) {
        Wall[] walls = new Wall[19];
        walls[0] = new Wall(city, 1, 4, Direction.EAST);
        walls[1] = new Wall(city, 2, 4, Direction.EAST);
        walls[2] = new Wall(city, 3, 4, Direction.EAST)
        walls[3] = new Wall(city, 4, 4, Direction.EAST);
        walls[4] = new Wall(city, 5, 4, Direction.EAST);   
        walls[5] = new Wall(city, 1, 3, Direction.NORTH);
        walls[6] = new Wall(city, 1, 2, Direction.NORTH);
        walls[7] = new Wall(city, 1, 1, Direction.NORTH);
        walls[8] = new Wall(city, 1, 0, Direction.NORTH);
        walls[9] = new Wall(city, 1, 4, Direction.NORTH); 
        walls[10] = new Wall(city, 5, 4, Direction.SOUTH);
        walls[11] = new Wall(city, 5, 3, Direction.SOUTH);
        walls[12] = new Wall(city, 5, 2, Direction.SOUTH);
        walls[13] = new Wall(city, 5, 1, Direction.SOUTH);
        walls[14] = new Wall(city, 5, 0, Direction.SOUTH); 
        walls[15] = new Wall(city, 1, 0, Direction.WEST);
        walls[16] = new Wall(city, 2, 0, Direction.WEST);
        walls[17] = new Wall(city, 3, 0, Direction.WEST);
        walls[18] = new Wall(city, 4, 0, Direction.WEST);
        walls[19] = new Wall(city, 5, 0, Direction.WEST); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Format your question properly

Comment: I'm all for using whitespace to improve readability, but doublespacing the code just makes it _more_ difficult to read.

Comment: The effects you describe aren't due to the "order of the code", at least not *as far as one can see from the code shown here*.

Comment: if these things are graphical they might overlap where one thing totally hides the other things

Comment: What are the second and third parameter? if these are _coordinates_ then several _things_ have the same ones. Is this intended?

Comment: Yes those are intentional.

Comment: I suspect you have a much more serious design issue. For example, side effects in constructors. You'll need to show the code for Wall, City, Robot, Thing for us to even get a hunch what's going on around here.

Comment: That's all the code i have for this program.

Comment: Where is `Robot` defined/implemented?

Comment: Where are the classes with package "becker.robots.*"? Is it a Jar without sourceCode?

Comment: Robot is already defined with the import .

Comment: Leave the order alone.  Try removing any Walls where the coordinates are the same as one of your objects.  If your objects show up, it's a drawing-order problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot spudone, you really helped me out. And also thanks to anybody who responded. i didn't expect my problem to be solved so quickly.